# How to Use Session or Cookies On Differnt Domains

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I want to share session  between two different domains .
How can I do this using cookie .  I want to share user id across two domains.

For example.

First website :  www.example.com In ASP.NET

Second website : www.newwebsite.com IN PHP

When user comes in first website , after login it will redirect to second website.

I want to get user id from first website cookie. How can I achieve this using cookie. My both website are on different platform and hosted on different server.

Code :

```
 // Create  cookie on First website : 

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("example "); 
    cookie.Values.add("Username", "user1");


    //Want to retrieve on Second website
    HttpCookie LoginCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("example ");
     string x = LoginCookie["Username"].ToString();
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are tied to individual sites/servers via (weak) encryption. What you will need to do is tell IIS that they are the same via the Machine Key inside your config. Arguably you could do this inside of IIS but then there is no source control.

Milan Mathew provided a decent start for you here (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/438319/Sharing-Authentication-Cookie-between-two-ASP-NET). Basically in both sites you apply the same encryption information.

```
<machineKey
     decryptionKey="A225194E99BCCB0F6B92BC9D82F12C2907BD07CF069BC8B4"
     validationKey="6FA5B7DB89076816248243B8FD7336CCA360DAF8" />
```

**Keep in mind that depending on which version of IIS and .NET** you are running will dictate how you set this up and which configs you apply this two. There have been recent modifications to how this is done.

Please provide more information for a more details on your setup for more specific assistance.

Any case, base your search criteria on this concept and you should be fine.

Comment: just for your information website one is in ASP.NET and Second One website is in PHP

Answer (score 0):

the HTTP protocol says, two different sites can share a cookie if and only if both sites are deployed under the same domain (or, sub-domain). Internally, your browser stores the cookies locally (either in disk or in memory) against the web site's URL. When you hit subsequent requests to any site, the browser reads those cookies which have matching domain or sub domain names comparing to the currently requested URL and sends those cookies with the request.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript/HTML5's "LocalStorage" feature, if you're on myDomain.com:81 and you set a value in local storage, but then redirect to myDomain.com, the local storage will be different, and the value will be lost.

How can I store a simple value that exists across all domains in my browser?

If it makes a difference, this is for a Chrome extension.

Comment: If you have a question, then [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one, don't "answer" an existing one.